# Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation; version="[2.8.0,3.0.0)"

Tags: osgi, build.gradle, liferay-7

IN my Liferay 7 project When i tried to add below dependency in build.gradle getting error

compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.8.8'

Err:

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation; version="[2.8.0,3.0.0)"

Comment: Sounds like you need fasterxml in the runtime.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on it @ChristianSchneider

Comment: Solved the issue by adding the below lines of code in bnd.bnd      
 Bundle-ClassPath:\
    .,\
   lib/jackson-annotations.jar,\
   lib/jackson-databind.jar,\
   lib/jackson-core.jar
   
-includeresource:\
  lib/jackson-annotations.jar=jackson-annotations-2.8.8.jar,\
  lib/jackson-databind.jar=jackson-databind-2.8.8.jar,\
  lib/jackson-core.jar=jackson-core-2.8.8.jar

Comment: Before adding the lines of code download jars

Comment: This will embed the jackson dependencies into your bundle. Alternatively you can try to install them as bundles. Embedding is good if this is the only bundle using them. Installing separately is better if you plan to have many such bundles.

Answer (score 2):

Download jackson-annotations-2.8.8.jar, jackson-core-2.8.8.jar & jackson-databind-2.8.8.jar bundles from [central repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) and put them in liferay-home\deploy folder. Check if they are installed properly in GoGo shell.

Answer (score 0):

Or You can use

> compileInclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name:'jackson-annotations', version: '2.8.0'

in **build.gradle**